# Assymptotic freedom significance

Tags: renormalization

So I have read a bit on this, and get the idea and mathematical machinery leading up to this. I get that it sheds light on the relationship between coupling strengths and length scales. Can someone tell me the "deep insight", or some other consequence of this that commanded a Nobel prize. Are there other physical implications I am missing?

Comment: 1) it explained nuclear forces and why quarks are never free 2)it came in a format that allowed the unification into the standard model SU(2)xSU(3)xU(1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't just "a" Nobel prize; it was one of the most well-deserved Nobel prizes in the history.

All interactions (forces) between particles known before this discovery of QCD had the property that their strength was increasing at shorter distances at a slightly faster rate than the $1/r^2$ classical law.

However, asymptotic freedom means that the charge carried by the quarks and gluons – their "color" – is actually getting weaker, not stronger, as we go to ever shorter distances. This is due to the "negative beta-function" of QCD, the first theory that was known to have a negative sign.

This sign has many implications. One of them is that with a great resolution seeing inside the proton and similar particles, quarks behave just like free particles. Protons have three "hard seeds" inside, very analogous to the nucleus inside the atom itself. This consequence of QCD had been known previously from experiments with "deep inelastic scattering". QCD totally explained these experiments.

Another consequence is that the "confinement" is pretty much the other side of the coin called "asymptotic freedom" (not quite, but close). If the interaction gets weaker at short distances, it becomes stronger at longer distances and that's why the individual quarks are confined: they don't exist in isolation. That explains why they were never separated from each other.

Consequently, QCD allowed the theory of quarks (or partons) to become acceptable. The theory  of quarks had previously looked like a bookkeeping device to organize hadrons into groups etc. Suddenly, it became clear that those particles were "really" composed of quarks. Hundreds of particles similar to the proton – hadrons – could suddenly be explained as composites of quarks (and gluons).

The asymptotically free "strong force" acting between quarks and gluons is now described by QCD, a $SU(3)$ Yang-Mills theory, and it is one of the four basic interactions that explain all processes we know in the Universe. The other ones are electromagnetism, gravity, and the weak nuclear interaction. The discovery of the asymptotic freedom was needed to make the strong force compatible with the experimentally known conditions on the would-be force between quarks. It's pretty much the most important property of the force, so the disoverers of this property may be considered the discoverers of the theory behind the strong force itself. In some counting, it is 1/4 of all of fundamental physics.

The asymptotic freedom also means that QCD becomes free and totally consistent at very short distances. Unlike QED, the theory is defined without any problems even if we consider arbitrarily high energies.